# Copy files through terminal in Automator

Tags: terminal, automator, cp

So the following issue seems to be caused within Automator but I cannot be sure (I would post an image but I don’t have enough points):

I have an Automator service whose first action is “Get Specified Finder Items” tool that goes to `~/Desktop/D53_C71J_C`. The next action is a “Run Shell Script” containing

```
PATH="$@"
echo "Path: $PATH"
cd "$PATH"
for f in *;
do
    echo "f: $f"
    CAT="$PATH/$f"
    echo "CAT: $CAT"
    cp "$f" ~/Desktop
done
```

The results are

```
Path: /Users/ajharn/Desktop/D53_C71J_C
f: D53_C71J_C1.psd
CAT: /Users/ajharn/Desktop/D53_C71J_C/D53_C71J_C1.psd

f: D53_C71J_C1_MERGE.psd
CAT: /Users/ajharn/Desktop/D53_C71J_C/D53_C71J_C1_MERGE.psd
f: D53_C71J_C2.psd
```

etc. It all works until it gets to `cp`. I’ve tested with echos and such and paths are lined up. The confusing part is that  `cp D53_C71J_C2.psd ~/Desktop` works fine in Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen your variable name very unwisely: `PATH` is used by the shell to store the path to directories where executables are located (see [the section on special shell parameters in the BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables) and the [bash man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sh.1.html)). As `cp` is an external program, not a shell command (it is found at `/bin/cp`), it is not found by the shell when you overwrite `PATH` with your current working path – and thus never runs.

Do something more along the lines of

```
[[ -d "$@" ]] && cd "$@"                # cd into folder if is one
for f in ./*; do                        # always prefix relative globs
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && cp "$f" ~/Desktop  # only copy files
done
```

and all will be well. Of course, adding a “Get Folder Contents” action and a “Move Finder Objects” one will work too, without any shell intervention.

Comment: Ah, I should've noticed such a basic word was probably a keyword. Thank you for those links as well. As I'm still pretty new to shell scripting I appreciate the explanations on why it was wrong too. Thank you very much for your help!